# Matlab: how to read a .txt file with many separators

Tags: matlab, floating-point

this is my first question here on stackoverflow. I have a problem reading a .txt file with *Matlab* using textread. The .txt, really messy, has a structure as below.

```
 "ALMEMO";"BEREICH:";"L420";"DIGI";"DIGI";"DIGI";"DIGI";;;;;;;"DIGI";"DIGI";"DIGI";"DIGI";;;;;;;"DIGI";"DIGI";"DIGI";"DIGI";;;;;;;"DIGI";"DIGI";"DIGI";"DIGI";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CuCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";;;;;;;;;;;"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo";"CoCo"
"5690-2";"KOMMENTAR:";"";"T,t       ";"T,t       ";"Temperatur";"T,t       ";;;;;;;"RH,Uw     ";"RH,Uw     ";"Feuchte   ";"RH,Uw     ";;;;;;;"DT,td      ";"DT,td     ";"Taupunkt  ";"DT,td     ";;;;;;;"MH,r g/kg ";"MH,r g/kg ";"Mischung  ";"MH,r g/kg ";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";;;;;;;;;;;"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";""
"SD3.10";"GW-MAX:";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
"ALMEMO.001";"GW-MIN:";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
"DATUM:";"ZEIT:";"M00: ms";"M01: øC";"M02: øC";"M03: øC";"M04: øC";;;;;;;"M11: %H";"M12: %H";"M13: %H";"M14: %H";;;;;;;"M21: øC";"M22: øC";"M23: øC";"M24: øC";;;;;;;"M31: gk";"M32: gk";"M33: gk";"M34: gk";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"M70: øC";"M71: øC";"M72: øC";"M73: øC";"M74: øC";"M75: øC";"M76: øC";"M77: øC";"M78: øC";"M79: øC";;;;;;;;;;;"M90: øC";"M91: øC";"M92: øC";"M93: øC";"M94: øC";"M95: øC";"M96: øC";"M97: øC";"M98: øC";"M99: øC"
07.03.21;11:29:24;0,;22,91;23,15;23,68;22,75;;;;;;;38,3;74,1;70,;38,8;;;;;;;8,;18,3;17,8;8,1;;;;;;;6,6;13,2;12,8;6,6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;;;;;;;;;;;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-
;11:30:24;0,;22,9;23,14;23,69;22,82;;;;;;;38,4;72,6;71,9;38,5;;;;;;;8,;18,;18,3;8,;;;;;;;6,6;12,9;13,2;6,6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;;;;;;;;;;;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-
;11:31:24;0,;22,94;23,14;23,68;22,88;;;;;;;38,3;75,4;71,5;38,5;;;;;;;8,;18,6;18,2;8,1;;;;;;;6,6;13,4;13,1;6,6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;;;;;;;;;;;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-
;11:32:24;0,;23,;23,13;23,68;22,95;;;;;;;38,2;73,;72,3;38,5;;;;;;;8,;18,1;18,4;8,1;;;;;;;6,6;13,;13,3;6,7;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;;;;;;;;;;;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-
```

six lines of header are followed by the actual data, that are separated by ';' and have the floating point numbers formatted with comas instead of dots. The data I need is not represented by the whole line but only the first nine elements (date, hour, 9 floating point numbers).

The code I wrote to read the file, a bit naively, looking at other codes, is the following:

```
[date1, hour1, V0, Temp1, Temp2, Temp3, Temp4, RH1, RH2, RH3, RH4] = textread('file.txt', '%c %c %f %f %f %f %f %c* %c* %c* %c* %c* %c* %f %f %f %f', 'headerlines', 7, 'delimiter', ';');
```

obviously it does not work. I think the headers should be skipped already in my version of the code, so, to summarize, the following questions remain:

- How can I treat many separators as one? (or ignore them, as I tried to do in my code)
- How can I make the date, that appears only in the first line after the header, appear in the whole code? (I think i can fill the first column of the output matrix afterwards with a for cycle)
- How can I cut the lines of the text file, ignoring everything that comes after the ninth floating point number?
  -How can I read coma separated floating point numbers? (I tried to convert them to dots with the notepad "Replace" function, this is a valid solution in my case, but still does not solve the problem)

Thanks in advance to everyone who will answer, take care,
Giuseppe

Comment: I don't know if MATLAB has enough flexibility to parse a file like that. Maybe it would be better if you used some other language (like PERL) to edit the files beforehand.

Comment: You should read the help for `textscan`. Specifically the `MultipleDelimitersAsOne` and `HeaderLines` options

Comment: If you read you whole file as a string you might consider postprocessing this string using  regexprep(strFile, '+;', ';') to replace multiple occurences of ; with a single one. You could then replace ',' with '.' using regexprep and get step by step to your final data representation you want

Comment: Thank you. I am elaborating on the code suggested by Morc and although I am not done yet I think I am on the good way to create an inelegant but effective code.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the built-in arguments for `textscan` to correctly handle the lines of the header and parse out the multiple delimiters. Then handle the commas for dots replacement with `strrep`. Finally, you can convert your cell array of strings to an array of numbers with `str2double`.

```
fid  = fopen('foo.txt');
C    = textscan(fid, repmat('%s',1,9), 'Headerlines', 6, 'Delimiter', ';', 'MultipleDelimitersAsOne', 1);
col1 = str2double( strrep(C{1}, ',', '.') );
```

Very roundabout way of accomplishing your task but text handling is not exactly matlab's strong point.